# Making a new field via module

Tags: entities

I've been following the Drupal example on how to create a new field. I can get their example to work fine, but when I try my own it does not seem to store any data, i.e. the field is always blank when I load the node back. I am ultimately attempting to create a field which can hold multiple pieces of information, a bit like the example three field color code. Although I would want a better storage then expanding a value into an array (I have an idea on this, but until I have the basic data storage working I cannot comment on this).

The example is [here](http://api.drupal.org/api/examples/field_example%21field_example.module/7).

This is my code from the module; I have stripped the example down to the bare minimum, and I have checked it works on the color wheel code.

```
 function prodlist_field_schema($field) {
  if ($field['type'] == 'prodlist_code') { 
      $columns = array(
        'prodcode' => array(
          'type' => 'varchar',
          'length' => 7,
          'not null' => FALSE,
        ),
      );
  }
  return array('columns' => $columns);
}

function prodlist_field_info() {
  return array(
    'prodlist_code' => array( 
      'label' => t('Product Code'),
      'description' => t('Used to assign product codes'),
      'default_widget' => 'prodlist_text',
      'default_formatter' => 'field_example_simple_text',
    ),
  );
}

function prodlist_field_widget_info() {
  return array(
     'prodlist_text' => array(
      'label' => t('Prodcode entry fields'),
      'field types' => array('prodlist_code'), 
    ),

  );
}

function prodlist_field_is_empty($item, $field) {
  return empty($item['prodlist_code']); 
}

function prodlist_field_widget_form(&$form, &$form_state, $field, $instance, $langcode, $items, $delta, $element) {
  $value = isset($items[$delta]['prodlist_code']) ? $items[$delta]['prodlist_code'] : 'emptyonload';

  $widget = $element;
  $widget['#delta'] = $delta;

    $widget += array(
          '#type' => 'textfield',
          '#title' => 'prodcode',
          '#size' => 23,
          '#default_value' => $value,
        );

  $element['prodcode'] = $widget; 
  return $element;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found another great example in the book "Drupal 7 Module Development", having worked through this example I am now able to alter it to my own purposes and the data is persistent.

Below is a working 3 field example.

```
function prodlist_field_info() {
  return array(
    'productorder' => array( 
      'label' => t('Product Code'),
      'description' => t('Used to assign product codes'),
      'default_widget' => 'prodlist_text',
      'default_formatter' => 'field_example_simple_text',
    ),
  );
}


function prodlist_field_schema($field) {
  if ($field['type'] =='productorder') {
      $schema['columns']['code'] = array(
        'type' => 'varchar',
        'length' => 10,
        'not null' => FALSE,
      );
      $schema['columns']['description'] = array(
        'type' => 'varchar',
        'length' => 10,
        'not null' => FALSE,
      );
      $schema['columns']['amount'] = array(
        'type' => 'int',
        'not null' => FALSE,
      );


      $schema['indexes'] = array(
        'code' => array('code'),
        'description' => array('description'),
        'amount' => array('amount'),
      );

      return $schema;
  }

}

function prodlist_field_is_empty($item, $field) {
  if ($field['type'] == 'productorder') {
    if (empty($item['code']) && empty($item['description']) && empty($item['amount']) ) {
      return TRUE;
    }
  }
  return FALSE;

}


function prodlist_field_widget_info() {
  return array(
     'prodlist_text' => array(
      'label' => t('Prodcode entry fields'),
      'field types' => array('productorder'), 

    ),

  );
}

function prodlist_field_widget_form(&$form, &$form_state, $field, $instance, $langcode, $items, $delta, $element) {
  $base = $element;

  if ($instance['widget']['type'] == 'prodlist_text') {
    $element['code'] = array(
      '#type' => 'textfield',
      '#title' => t('Code'),
      '#default_value' => isset($items[$delta]['code']) ? $items[$delta]['code'] : NULL) + $base;
    $element['description'] = array(
      '#type' => 'textfield',
      '#title' => t('Description'),
      '#default_value' => isset($items[$delta]['description']) ? $items[$delta]['description'] : NULL) + $base;
    $element['amount'] = array(
      '#type' => 'textfield',
      '#title' => t('Amount'),
      '#default_value' => isset($items[$delta]['amount']) ? $items[$delta]['amount'] : NULL) + $base;

  }
  return $element;

}
```